# ASP.Net MVC 3 Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.Net MVC 3 and interested to learn Ajax implementation in MVC.

Is there any ebook or tutorial to learn AJAX in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx

[asp.net MVC3 and jquery AJAX tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655466/asp-net-mvc3-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',  
        data: { },
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
   success: function (result) {
            alert(data)
        } });
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would improve your answer considerably.

Comment: AJAX is an acronym standing for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML and this technology help us to load data from the server without a browser page refresh.

If you are new with AJAX, I would recommend you go through our Ajax Tutorial before proceeding further.

JQuery is a great tool which provides a rich set of AJAX methods to develop next generation web application.

Comment: I know what AJAX is. See also the following help-page: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)